# Visual Studio 2017 64-bit IDE?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Did they finally make x64 IDE for VS2017?

I am asking because I have ~200 projects in solution and it works bad when all are loaded, slowly eats up to 2.5GB of memory and then freezes. [vsFunnel](http://vsfunnel.com/) helps, but I would prefer x64 IDE.

[EDIT1]: This is something new for big solutions in VS 2017: [Enable lightweight solution load](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/optimize-visual-studio-startup-time#speed-up-solution-load)

Comment: VS 2017 loads many projects much better than VS 2015; the [Funnel extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DimitriDering.Funnel) further benefits this (ignore the VS 2017-specific API warning as it's still very useful/relevant). I usually run < 1GB on "hundreds of projects in solution" with only relevant projects loaded at once with the ability to switch fairly fast. There are still some pesky "memory leaks", but it's much more manageable than VS 2015 .. even if the process still chokes ~2.2GB. 64-bit support would be awesome, but I'll take whatever I can get :}

Answer (score 15):

No.

(And plenty of requests here are there for handling bigger solutions and/or process dumps.)

Comment: They did, however, dramatically improve solution loading times and memory usage, so the upgrade could still help.

Comment: Although I hoped x64, if they improved memory usage it could be better. I have noticed that in VS 2015 only changing target platform from A to B and back for several times caused memory footprint to grow on each change. I guess it was some kind of memory leak there.

Comment: Oh, this is something new: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/optimize-visual-studio-startup-time#speed-up-solution-load

Answer (score 0):

**VS2019** may help, it is not fully 64-bit but they say the **debugger runs on 64-bit process** and demo with Gear of War code in VS2019 keynotes launch day.

[GoW debugging at 38:00](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DANLUUIUrcM&t=2280s)

You may need to switch to **VSCode** or **VS for Mac** for full **64-bit experience**.

I hit this question because on Azure Education they launch VS2017 with both 64 and 32-bit system, I'm curious but it till installing with the same installer and in the same Program Files (x86) folder, and when I try to change the folder it says

> Visual Studio cannot be installed to a nonempty directory
>   'C:\ProgramData...\